# Modifying appsettings.json in .NET Core Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have searched a lot for modifying `appsettings.json` in .NET Core. There are lots of Articles, Blogs and Wikis on Reading the Settings. Like [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) And [this one](http://benjii.me/2016/04/new-configuration-appsettings-mvc6-web-config-gone/). But I couldn't find any solutions for writing the `appsettings.json` Programmatically.

Is there any way to write settings programmatically. Like the one we used to do when saving appsettings in web.config?

Comment: When did you ever save appsettings to web.config programmatically? In classic .NET that would cause an immediate app restart.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: So, its not possible right? I'm just curious to know. I have already understood that its not the right thing to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update values into appsetting.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970944/how-to-update-values-into-appsetting-json)