# How to access IConfigurationRoot in startup on .net core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have written a custom `ConfigurationProvider` with the entity framework. Since I also want to make it updateable during runtime, I have created a [`IWritableableOption`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705862/2441442).

I need to refresh the configuration after the update. This can be done via [`IConfigurationRoot.Reload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.iconfigurationroot.reload?view=aspnetcore-2.0).

However, how can I get the `IConfigurationRoot` in .net core 2?

What I have found, is that in previous versions the `IConfigurationRoot` was part of startup. In .net core 2 however, we have only the simpler type `IConfiguration`:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    // I tried to change this to IConfigurationRoot,
    // but this results in an unresolved dependency error
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

I also have found out, I can get my own instance using

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureAppConfiguration(context, builder) => {
    var configurationRoot = builder.build()
})
```

But I want to update the configuration used by Startup.

So how can I get the `IConfigurationRoot` used by `Startup` to inject it into my service collection?

Comment: The `configuration` parameter passed in `Startup` - isn't that an instance of `ConfigurationRoot` which implements both `IConfiguration` and `IConfigurationRoot`?

Comment: Yeah, downcasting works, but I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it @Dealdiane

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks to [Dealdiane's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48939567/how-to-access-iconfigurationroot-in-startup-on-net-core-2#comment84887990_48939567) comment.

We can downcast the `IConfiguration`:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = (IConfigurationRoot)configuration;
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
```

I am still not sure, if this is the intended way, since `IConfiguration` does not make any guarantees about `IConfigurationRoot`.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can inject it before initialization of the `Startup`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = null;
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                 .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
                  {
                      configurationRoot = builder.Build();
                  })
                  .ConfigureServices(services =>
                  {
                      services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(configurationRoot);
                      services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configurationRoot);
                  })
                 .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```