# Can I update appsettings.json file through code in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings

I have a simple console app to test some DLL's I have made. There is an `appsettings.json` file in my test console app and I want to update that file based of the response coming from the DLL(s). I have searched a lot but to no avail.

Comment: Did you check this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970944/how-to-update-values-into-appsetting-json

Comment: @HardikPatel yes i've tried this solution but it is not  working in my program. like "IOptionsWriter" is not even supported i guess. i have added Nuget package IOptionsWriter but despite that it didn't work. Kindy suggest any other work around. thanks

Comment: It's just _json_, so you should be able read it, modify it, rewrite it as such. Are you looking for functionality that's specific to the fact that it's a configuration file?