# How can I bind to a configuration class using ConfigurationBulder

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, .net-core-configuration

I want to use `ConfigurationBuidler` to read my `appsettings.json` file. I cant see what I am doing wrong.

My file is

```
{
  "comment": "this gets copied to bin\\debug on build. the app updates the copy. However to remember the settings you need to paste them here",
  "col1Width": "344"
}
```

My test fails

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var configuration = Helper.LoadConfiguration("appsettings.json");
    Assert.IsTrue(configuration.Properties.Keys.Contains("col1Width")); // fails here
}
```

My helper class is:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static ConfigurationBuilder LoadConfiguration(string filename)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        var currentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        configuration.SetBasePath(currentDirectory);
        configuration.AddJsonFile(path: filename, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        configuration.Build();
        return configuration;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I corrected the question title and updated the code as follows according to the Blog Post Marco pointed me to.

Only `Bind()` is not available

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static FeedReadConfiguration GetApplicationConfiguration( )
    {
        var configuration = new FeedReadConfiguration();
        var currentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var iConfig = GetIConfigurationRoot(currentDirectory);

        iConfig
            .GetSection("FeedRead")
            .Bind(configuration); // Not available

        return configuration;
    }

    public static IConfigurationRoot GetIConfigurationRoot(string outputPath)
    {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(outputPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
    }
    
}
public class FeedReadConfiguration
{
    public int Col1Width { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Question byside: Why are you returning `ConfigurationBuilder` not the built `IConfiguration`?

Comment: I think your appSettings.json files are not placed in your test project. Place app settings file from the actual project to test the project.

Comment: Kirsten, this might help you: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Feb/18/Accessing-Configuration-in-NET-Core-Test-Projects

Comment: Is the test failing (Assert?) or is there an exception throw with a detailed exception message. F.e. File not found because of: `optional: false`?

Comment: Thanks @Martin I updated the question to show it is the Assert that fails. I am also re-writing to use IConfiguration.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for that. Bind() is not working in .Net 3.1

Comment: @KirstenGreed based on the shown settings there is no `FeedRead` section

Comment: applies to Net 6 MSTest project ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the shown settings file, there is no `"FeedRead"` section

The settings would need to be read directly from the root.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public static class Helper {
    public static FeedReadConfiguration GetApplicationConfiguration( ) {
        
        var currentDirectory = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var iConfig = GetIConfigurationRoot(currentDirectory);

        //Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll
        FeedReadConfiguration configuration = iConfig.Get<FeedReadConfiguration>();

        return configuration;
    }

    public static IConfiguration GetIConfigurationRoot(string outputPath) {
        return new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(outputPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
    }    
}
```

*(requires [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json))*

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

Reference [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options)

Comment: IConfigurationRoot does not have a get method. It has GetChildren but that is not useful for binding.

Comment: @KirstenGreed extension method. make sure you have the necessary references.

Comment: @KirstenGreed review this sections specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bind-to-an-object-graph

Comment: @KirstenGreed plus configuration module is independent of asp.net, so it can be used outside of asp.net environment.

Comment: @Kirsten What is FeedReadConfiguration  ? winforms sample with net 6 configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

for anyone finding this question match the solution is to add the nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder

Then ops updated code will work.