# Dependency injection for IOptions

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.  `IOptions<ConnectionStrings>` is not updating with new values.

appSettings.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Database": "UserID={0};Password={1};Host=xyz.com;Port=5432;Database=xyz;Pooling=true;SSL Mode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true"
  }
```

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .SetSecretsAsEnvironmentVariables() //where I am setting environment variable from secret.json
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
                {
                    var env = hostContext.HostingEnvironment;
                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);                        config.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        config.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
                    }
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
```

StartUp:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }
public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; private set; }
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            this.HostingEnvironment = env;
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }


private void ConfigureAppSettings(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
            Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Bind(Service.Configuration.Configuration.ConnectionStrings);
            Service.Configuration.Configuration.ConnectionStrings.Database =
                                string.Format(Service.Configuration.Configuration.ConnectionStrings.Database, "abc",
                                    "xyz"); //here I am setting up new value for UserID and Password.

        }
```

MyConnectionFactory.cs

```
 public class ConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
    {
        private readonly ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;

        public ConnectionFactory(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
        {
            _connectionStrings = connectionStrings.Value;// Here connection string values are always withn{0},{1}.
        }

        public NpgsqlConnection CreateOpenConnection()
        {
            var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionStrings.QuoteDatabase);
            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        }
```

In my ServiceRegistry.cs

```
ForSingletonOf<IConnectionFactory>().Use<MyConnectionFactory>();
    
ForSingletonOf<ConnectionStrings>().Use(new ConnectionStrings() { Database = Configuration.Configuration.ConnectionStrings.Database });
```

Don't know What I am doing wrong here. My Connection string values are not updating with new values. If I am changing in MyConnectionFactory.cs from `IOptions<ConnectionStrings>` to `ConnectionStrings` the values are updating with new one.

Please anyone me help me out here.

Comment: Could you explain me what is this code is doing ? 
  Service.Configuration.Configuration.ConnectionStrings.Database =....
where is the value is stored ?
and what is the result of  Configuration.Configuration.ConnectionStrings.Database  in your  ServiceRegistry.cs

Comment: This one is I am reading value from Environment Variable and Setting up Database UserId and Password value

Comment: Why not reading environment variable when using the connection string in `ConnectionFactory` class? I think it's much easier that this [high vote answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42705862/14574199) about updating value in appsetting file.